# Calculate the time delay between send and received packets using iperf3 and tcpdump?

Tags: python, numpy-ndarray, tcpdump, tshark, iperf3

I have written a bash code to run iperf3 and capture packets. Then i have extracted frame time from the .pcap file using tshark. The time is in the following format **Jan 27, 2020 13:22:12.683438000 CET.**

Now i want to calculate the time difference between the sent and received packets, but I dont know how do i subtract time which is in this format.
Which variable type should i use so that I can perform the subtraction.

I have also used datetime library but did not get results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check if below lines can help you

```
from datetime import datetime
from pytz import timezone

CET = timezone('CET')

send_time = datetime.strptime('11:18:57.925 Wed Jan 5 2019', '%H:%M:%S.%f %a %b %d %Y')
print(send_time.astimezone(CET))
difference_from_now = send_time.astimezone(CET) - datetime.now().astimezone(CET)
print(difference_from_now)

received_time = datetime.strptime('08:18:57.925 Mon Jan 20 2020', '%H:%M:%S.%f %a %b %d %Y')
print(received_time.astimezone(CET))

difference_send_received = send_time.astimezone(CET) - received_time.astimezone(CET)

print(difference_send_received)
```

Comment: I want the time to be in the format Jan 27, 2020 13:22:12.683438000 CET, which has 9 digits after decimal point in seconds. How do I do that?

Comment: @Nehal , your question is about get the difference , hope my code answers it, for different , and difference cannot come zone name, it will always be in day , min, sec , years, etc,  in formatting following links can help ... http://pytz.sourceforge.net/ and https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html